# materialize nav bar with search and dropdown button?

Tags: html, css, nav, materialize

Welcome to my third question on SO in like 7 years. I've been pretty good at lurking.

Anywho, I'm working with the Materialize framework and trying to create a search nav bar with a vertical dropdown on the right side. Here is what my code looks like at the moment:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s10">
        <form>
          <div class="input-field">
            <input id="search" type="search" />
            <label for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col s2">
        <ul class="right">
          <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
          <i class="material-icons dropdown-button btn" href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>reorder</i></a>

          <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
          <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
            <li><a href="/">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I would like for the nav bar to be transparent until I click on it, when the whole bar turns white for the search feature. The dropdown on the right side should be inside the nav bar, and when I click on that, Logout appears below. As you can see from the two photos, the whole bar isn't turning white (I'm assuming because I've got it in a col s10), and the dropdown isn't dropping below, but rather on top of.

[image: Dropdown error]

[image: Search bar error]

Thank you for any help, and please let me know if there's any other code you'd like to see!

Comment: something like https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/qty77hec/5/ ?

Comment: Well that was easy, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

To get the dropdown below you need to add 
`data-beloworigin="true"`
to dropdown trigger.

And, to get it inside nav you need to give it `position:absolute;`

Here's the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/link2pk/qty77hec/5/)